annihilator polynomial and cyclic subspaces
Suppose $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, and $T:V\rightarrow V$ is some linear map, which isn't the zero map. The annihilator of a vector $v\not=0$ by the linear map $T$ is a monic polynomial $p\in F[x]$ with the min. degree s.t $p(T)(v)=0$. My question is why for every $u\in Z(v;T)$ (The T-cyclic subspace generated by $v$), $p(T)(u)=0$. The only proof for this fact that I saw was the following: If $u\in Z(v,T)$, then $u=f(T)(v)$ for some $f\in F[x]$, and so $p(T)(v)=f(T)(v)=f(T)p(T)(v)=f(T)(0)=0.$ But I could not understant why p(T) commute with f(T). [The mult. here stands for function composition]

What is $Z(v,T)$? Anyway, $p(T)$ and $f(T)$ commute because $p(T)f(T)=(pf)(T)=(fp)(T)=f(T)p(T)$, where $pf=fp$ because polynomial multiplication is commutative.

@Mark $Z(v;T)$ is the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$
